# Idiomatic use of std::auto_ptr or only use shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, coding-style, smart-pointers, tr1

Now that `shared_ptr` is in tr1, what do you think should happen to the use of `std::auto_ptr`? They both have different use cases, but all use cases of `auto_ptr` can be solved with `shared_ptr`, too. Will you abandon `auto_ptr` or continue to use it in cases where you want to express explicitly that only one class has ownership at any given point?

My take is that using `auto_ptr` can add clarity to code, precisely by adding nuance and an indication of the design of the code, but on the other hand, it add yet another subtle issue when training new programmers: they need to understand smart pointers and the fine details of how they work. When you use only one smart pointer everywhere, you can just lay down a rule 'wrap all pointers in `shared_ptr`' and be done with it.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To provide a little more ammunition to the 'avoid `std::auto_ptr`' camp:  `auto_ptr` is being deprecated in the next standard (C++0x).  I think this alone is good enough ammunition for any argument to use something else.

However, as [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197048/idiomatic-use-of-stdautoptr-or-only-use-sharedptr#197083) mentioned, the default replacement for `auto_ptr` should probably be `boost::scoped_ptr`.  The semantics of `scoped_ptr` more closely match those of `auto_ptr` and it is intended for similar uses.  The next C++09 standard will have something similar called unique_ptr.

However, using `shared_ptr` anywhere that `scoped_ptr` should be used will not break anything, it'll just add a very slight bit of inefficiency to deal with the reference count if the object is never actually going to be shared.  So for private member pointers that will never be handed out to another object - use `scoped_ptr`.  If the pointer will be handed out to something else (this includes using them in containers or if all you want to do is transfer ownership and not keep or share it) - use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Mike, unfortunately there is no `tr1::scoped_ptr`. Apparently they wanted to keep it simple. I don't know about the status in TR2 but since the next standard will introduce the `unique_ptr` instead, I doubt there will be a `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Accepted this one, didn't know auto_ptr was being deprecated. Like you say, that alone is an authoritative reason to not use it; I liked MSalters' example of 'relinquish ownership semantics', though.

Answer (score 28):

auto_ptr is nice in signatures, too. When a function takes an `auto_ptr<T>` by value, it means it will consume the `T`. If a function returns an `auto_ptr<T>`, it's clear that it relinquishes ownership. This can communicate your intents about the lifetime.

On the other hand, using `scoped_ptr<T>` implies that you don't want to care about the lifetime of the `T`. This also implies you can use it in more places. Both smart pointers are valid choices, you can certainly have both in a single program.

Comment: Best description of what auto_ptr should be used for.

Answer (score 11):

"Use `shared_ptr` everywhere" is a good default rule, and certainly a good starting point for teaching people about responsible use of smart pointers. However, it's not always the best choice.

If you don't need shared ownership, `shared_ptr` is overkill: it has to allocate a separate memory block for the reference count, which can impact performance, and it is less clear documentation-wise.

Personally, I use `std::auto_ptr` in many places where `boost::scoped_ptr` would also suffice: e.g. holding a heap-allocated object before ownership is transferred elsewhere, where the intervening operations might throw.

C++0x will have `std::unique_ptr` to complement `std::shared_ptr` as a better alternative to `std::auto_ptr`. When it becomes widely available I'll start using that.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that it's best-practice is to substitute all uses of `std::auto_ptr` by [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) unless `std::tr1::shared_ptr` meets the requirements better, *if* you don't mind using Boost. On the other hand, it was surely intentional that `scoped_ptr` wasn't included in TR1.

Comment: scoped_ptr has its use, namely single-ownership that doesn't require transfer. In those cases, it should take the place of auto_ptr. However, where single-ownership, transfer semantics is appropriate, auto_ptr should still be used. :-)

Comment: What makes scoped_ptr better than a const auto_ptr? There is an item about auto_ptr in Exceptional C++ and a paragraph especially about const auto_ptr; from reading about scoped_ptr I don't see any advantages over a const auto_ptr.

Comment: `auto_ptr` may yield ownership. Often, this isn't required. Basically, a `scoped_ptr` implements just RAII for an arbitrary pointer in a given block.

Comment: const auto_ptr can't yield ownership. The copy constructor takes a non-const reference. I would still use scoped_ptr though as I think it conveys the intent a little bit better.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that "wrap all pointers in `shared_ptr`" should indeed be the default mode, and is suitable advice to give to your junior coders. However, in the special ownership cases that you mentioned, `auto_ptr` is indeed more appropriate and its use should be encouraged under such circumstances.