# What are the practical differences between C compilers on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cross-platform

A program written in Visual C/C++ 2005/2008 might not compile with another compiler such as GNU C/C++ or vice-versa. For example when trying to reuse code, which uses windows.h, written for a particular compiler with another, what are the differences to be aware of?

Is there any information about how to produce code which is compatible with either one compiler or another e.g. with either GC/C++ or MSVC/C++? What problems will attempting to do this cause?

What about other compilers, such as LCC and Digital Mars?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to do when trying to compile code written for MSVC to other compilers is to compile it with Microsoft-extensions switched off. (Use the /Za flag, I think). That will smoke out lots of things which GCC and other compilers will complain about.

The next step is to make sure that Windows-specific APIs (MFC, Win32, etc.) are isolated in Windows-specific files, effectively partioning your code into "generic" and "windows-specific" modules.

Answer (score 6):

Remember the argument that if you want your web page to work on different browsers, then you should write standards-compliant HTML?

Same goes for compilers.

At the language level, if your code compiles without warnings on GCC with -std=c89 (or -std=c++98 for C++), -pedantic -Wall, plus -Wextra if you're feeling brave, and as long as you haven't used any of the more blatant GNU extensions permitted by -pedantic (which are hard to do accidentally) then it has a good chance of working on most C89 compilers. C++ is a bit less certain, as you're potentially relying on how complete the target compiler's support is for the standard.

Writing correct C89 is somewhat restrictive (no // comments, declarations must precede statements in a block, no inline keyword, no stdint.h and hence no 64bit types, etc), but it's not too bad once you get used to it. If all you care about is GCC and MSVC, you can switch on some language features you know MSVC has. Otherwise you can write little "language abstraction" headers of your own. For instance, one which defines "inline" as "inline" on GCC and MSVC/C++, but "__inline" for MSVC/C. Or a MSVC stdint.h is easy enough to find or write.

I've written portable code successfully in the past - I was working mostly on one platform for a particular product, using GCC. I also wrote code that was for use on all platforms, including Windows XP and Mobile. I never compiled it for those platforms prior to running a "test build" on the build server, and I very rarely had any problems. I think I might have written bad code that triggered the 64bit compatibility warning once or twice.

The Windows programmers going the other way caused the occasional problem, mostly because their compiler was less pedantic than ours, so we saw warnings they didn't, rather than things that GCC didn't support at all. But fixing the warnings meant that when the code was later used on systems with more primitive compilers, it still worked.

At the library level, it's much more difficult. If you #include and use Windows APIs via windows.h, then obviously it's not going to work on linux, and the same if you use KDE with GCC and then try to compile with MSVC.

Strictly speaking that's a platform issue, not a compiler issue, but it amounts to the same thing. If you want to write portable code, you need an OS abstraction API, like POSIX (or a subset thereof) that all your targets support, and you need to be thinking "portable" when you write it in the first place. Taking code which makes heavy use of windows-specific APIs, and trying to get it to work on GCC/linux, is basically a complete rewrite AFIAK. You might be better off with WINE than trying to re-compile it.

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing up "compilers" and "OSs". <windows.h> is not something that MSVC C compiler brings to the table: it's C-specific embodiment of Windows API. You can get it independently from Visual Studio. Any other C compiler on Windows is likely to provide it. On the Linux side, for example, you have <unistd.h>, <pthereads.h> and others. They are not an essential part of GCC, and any other compiler that compiles for Linux would provide them.

So you need to answer two different questions: how can I code C in such a way that any compiler accepts it? And how do I hide my dependencies on OS?

Answer (score 5):

As you can tell from the diverse answers, this topic is fairly involved.  Bearing that in mind here are some of the issues I faced when recently porting some code to target three platforms (msvc 8/Windows, gcc 4.2/Linux, gcc 3.4/embedded ARM9 processor).  It was originally only compiling under Visual Studio 2005.

a) Much code that's written on the Windows platforms uses types defined in windows.h.  I've had to create a "windows_types.h" file with the following in it:

```
#ifndef _WIN32
    typedef short              INT16;
    typedef unsigned short     UINT16;
    typedef int                INT32;
    typedef unsigned int       UINT32;
    typedef unsigned char      UCHAR;
    typedef unsigned long long UINT64;
    typedef long long          INT64;
    typedef unsigned char      BYTE;
    typedef unsigned short     WORD;
    typedef unsigned long      DWORD;
    typedef void *             HANDLE;
    typedef long               LONG;
#endif
```

Ugly, but much easier than modifying the code that, previously, was only targeting Windows.

b) The typename keyword was not required in templated code to declare types.  MSVC is lax in this regard (though I assume certain compiler switches would have generated a warning).  Had to add it in a number of places.

c) Simple, but time-consuming: Windows is not case sensitive and many #included files were specified with incorrect case causing problems under Linux.

d) There was a fair chunk of code using the Windows API for many things.  An example was for CRITICAL_SECTIONS and INTERLOCKED_INCREMENT.  We used the boost libraries as much as possible to replace these issues but reworking code is time-consuming.

e) A lot of the code relied on headers being included in precompiled headers.  We had issues with using pch on gcc3.4 so we had to ensure that all .h/cpp files correctly included all their dependencies (as they should have in the first place).

f) VS 2005 has two nasty bugs.  [auto_ptr's can be assigned to anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/replacing-autoptr-in-vc-8) and temporary variables are allowed to be passed to reference parameters.  Both fail to compile (thankfully!) under gcc but rework is required.

g) Bizarrely, we had template code that was trying to explicitly specialise *class* template functions.  Not allowed.  Again gcc refused, VS 2005 let it go.  Easy enough to rework into regular overloads once the problem is understood.

h) Under VS 2005 std::exception is allowed to be constructed with a string.  Not allowed under gcc or the standard.  Rework your code to prefer to use one of the derived exception classes.

Hopefully that's the kind of information you were looking for!

Comment: Great list. I've observed every single one you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Well this is a quite difficult question. Fact is that MSVC does not support the newest
C standard, about it's c++ compliance I can tell you anyything. Howerver "windows" C is understand by both MSVC and gcc you just can not hope for the other way. E.g if you use ANSI C99 features then you might have a hard time "porting" from gcc to MSVC.

But as  long as you try the way MSVC-> gcc you chances will be better. The only point you have to be aware of is the libraries. Most of the libraries on Windows are supposed to work with MSVC and so you need some extra tools to make them accessible to gcc also.

LCC is a quite older system,which AFAIKT does not support much from ANSI C99, it also needs tools from MSVC to work properly. LCC is "just " a compiler.

lcc-win32 is a C Development system striving to be ANSI C99 compliant. It comes along with linker,  IDE etc.

I can not tell about the state of Digital Mars implementation

Then there is also Pelles-C which is a fully fledged IDE also.

And we have hanging around OpenWatcom. Which once was quite a decent system but I can't tell how conformant it is.

All in all the "best" you can hope  for the easier way from MSVC -> other system but it will probably be much worse the other way round.

Regards
Friedrich

Answer (score 1):

> A program written in Visual C/C++ 2005/2008 might not compile with another compiler such as GNU C/C++ or vice-versa.

This is true if you either (1) use some sort of extension available in one compiler but not another (the C++ standard, for instance requires the `typename` and `template` keywords in a few places but many compilers -- including Visual C++ don't enforce this; gcc used to not enforce this either, but [changed in 3.4](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/bugs.html#new34)) or (2) use some standard compliant behavior implemented on one compiler but not another (right now the poster boy for this is exported templates, but only one or two compilers support this, and Visual C++ and gcc are not in that group).

> For example when trying to reuse code, which uses windows.h, written for a particular compiler with another,

I've never seen a problem doing this.  I have seen a problem using Microsoft's windows.h in gcc.  But when I use gcc's windows.h in gcc and Microsoft's windows.h in Visual C++ I have access to all of the documented functions.  That's the definitions of "implemented windows.h" after all.

> what are the differences to be aware of?

The main one I've seen is people not knowing about the dependent `template`/`typename` thing mentioned above.  I find it funny that a number of people think gcc is not smart enough to do what Visual C++ does, when in reality gcc had the feature first and then decided to remove it in the name of standards compliance.

In the near future you will run into problems using C++0x features.  But both gcc and Visual C++ have implemented the easier things in that standard.

Answer (score 1):

vs2008 is a lot more standards compliant than 2005.
I have had more problems going the other way, especially the 'feature' of gcc that lets you allocate an array with a variable size at run time "int array[variable]" which is just pure evil.

Comment: gcc did allow it before it became standard. IIRC it also allows it in C++ code