# auto_ptr or shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, auto-ptr, visual-c++-2005

In a C++03 environment, would you use an `auto_ptr` or a (boost) `shared_ptr` to return a resource from a function? (Where in C++11 one would naturally use a `unique_ptr`.)

```
auto_ptr<T> f() {
  ...
  return new T();
}
```

or

```
shared_ptr<T> f() {
  ...
  return new T();
}
```

`auto_ptr` has quite some pitfalls (not the least that it's construction is [awfully buggy on MSVC 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270347/321013) which is what I have to use), but `shared_ptr` seems like overkill ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer *purely* is applicable to auto_ptr use with a buggy implementation like the one in VS2005.

I will add my own view after trying with `auto_ptr` *on VS 2005*:

I have already used auto_ptr (on this VC++8) successfully in pure local contexts in the past, that is:

```
auto_ptr<T> local( ... ); // Don't use "=" to init! Will Crash on VS2005!
// use local
...
// Sometimes:
m_managing_object.setStuff( local.release() );
// Or, alternatively:
return local.release();
```

This worked well enough, and the only thing that could go haywire was using assignment syntax for init, which just reliably crashes every time so it wasn't a big deal.

So, agreeing on the implied semantics mentioned by others, I tried to get my inital example to work

```
auto_ptr<T> f() {
  ...
  return new T();
}
...
auto_ptr<T> pT( f() ); // or "=" init??, Variations ...
...
```

**Fail!**

After fiddling with this trivial example for about 1h30, I *still* didn't find out why and how exactly `auto_ptr` crashed every time when used this way.

I'm pretty sure that this is due to the buggy implementation of VS2005, that is, I may have done something completely bonkers that a bug-free implementation would've caught but here it crashed and I failed to get it right.

What does this mean: It means I'm using VS2005 with C++ for over 5 years now, I'm pretty confident at debugging even the weirdest scenarios, and after over an hour I *still* hadn't fiddled out what I did wrong. I'm sure I'd have found out eventually, but if an thing is so damn easy to misuse, I'd rather use `shared_ptr` and be done with it. Hell, even a raw pointer return is better, at least the worst thing you'll get with that is a memleak (easily detectable one).

So: Stay clear of all but the most trivial use cases of auto_ptr on VS2005.

Comment: `return new T();` shouldn't compile but does because the `auto_ptr_ref` mechanism is too liberal in the VS2005 implementation  (IIRC). `return std::auto_ptr<T>(new T());` should work fine on VS2005. Although it accepts some code that shouldn't compile with potentially undesirable behaviour; IIRC, all conforming uses of `auto_ptr` do work OK on VS2005.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - Thought I tried that too, not sure today. Anyways, problem is that the compiler doesn't catch the non-conforming uses.

Answer (score 6):

In C++03, I would use either a bare pointer or an `auto_ptr` and let the caller decide on the ownership strategy.

Note that one of the pitfalls of smart pointers is that *covariance* does not apply to them, meaning that you can override `Base* f()` by `Derived* f()` but you cannot override `std::x_ptr<Base> f()` by `std::x_ptr<Derived> f()`; and thus in this case you have no choice but to use a simple pointer.

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. Passing a `shared_ptr` says "I want to share this object with you." This function clearly isn't going to be using the object any more, though, so that's the wrong semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `shared_ptr` or a raw pointer because `auto_ptr` is considered a bad idea.

It really depends on your *ownership* semantics.  Who will destroy the owned resource?

Comment: I disagree on the *makes sense*, for all its pitfalls `auto_ptr` does implement (poorly) move semantics which are closer to the goal.

Comment: Why is `auto_ptr` considered a bad idea [in C++03]? Surely it encapsulates complete transfer of ownership out of a function better than a raw pointer and a `shared_ptr`?