# storing pointers to auto_ptr in vector

Tags: c++, vector, containers, auto-ptr

Can one store pointers to auto_ptr(s) in a std::vector?  Is it safe?

I enumerate a folder reading in XML files and creating an object for each with auto_ptr.  I don't know in advance how many XML files there will be and I'd like to use a vector to essentially keep a list of pointers to them.

I'm also assuming that when a pointers are removed from the Vector (or the vector is destroyed) the pointers are pretty much gone, so I wouldn't have to worry about setting them to NULL.

Comment: Do you mean can you store auto_ptrs in a vector? Or do you really mean pointers to auto_ptrs?

Comment: Storing raw pointers to smart pointers kind of defeats the purpose of using smart pointers...

Answer (score 4):

You can't store an `auto_ptr` itself in a `std::vector`, but storing a plain pointer is fine, even if the thing it points *to* is an `auto_ptr`.

I don't see why you'd want to do that, though.  The whole point of `auto_ptr` is to ensure that heap-allocated objects are deleted automatically when they go out of scope.  You lose that benefit if the `auto_ptr` itself has to be deleted manually.

If you want to store heap-allocated objects safely in a vector, you can use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr`, or use Boost's pointer containers.  Or, if you're using C++11, `std::unique_ptr` is like `std::auto_ptr` except it's safe to use in containers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could - but it is totally unsafe and will do all sorts of unexpected things that will surprise you.

If you want to store smart pointers in a container have a look at unique_ptr if your compiler supports C++11 stuff

Comment: And if you're not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197048/idiomatic-use-of-stdauto-ptr-or-only-use-shared-ptr for discussion of pre-C++11 options.

Comment: If the pointers that I'm storing are ordinary pointers to auto_ptr then why would there be unexpected results?  Assuming that the auto_ptr(s) aren't destroyed before the vector.

Comment: Pointers to auto_ptr's would work (because you avoid the only 1 auto_ptr can own the data). But since you have to reallocate the auto_ptr's why not just store pointers to your items in the vector